# Flutter - How check new verson with Firebase Remote Config

Tags: flutter

I try to check if my app has new version. If has new version shows a modal to force to update. I use the [firebase remote config](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config) package.

The code looks

```
versionCheck(context) async {
        PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
        await remoteConfig.fetch();
        await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
        final currentBuildNumber = int.parse(info.buildNumber);
        final requiredBuildNumber = remoteConfig
            .getInt('android_app_version');
        if (requiredBuildNumber > currentBuildNumber) {
          versionDialog(context);
        }
      }
```

[image: The config keys]

The problem: currentBuildNumber return the correct number, but the requiredBuildNumber always return '50', so the if conditional doesn´t work as expected. Something is wrong but don't i don't know what. What´s is the rigth way to do this?

Comment: Correctly if I'm wrong. If you execute e.g. `print(requiredBuildNumber)` you see `50` **always** instead of 48?

Comment: Yes, is correct. I don´t know why prints  50 :$ ¿Maybe is default number or something like that?

Comment: Have you ever set that vairable to `50` in past? Remote config has some expiration time. It might be possible that it is still serving from cache? Can you try removing App data and try again?

Comment: Fixed adding     await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: Duration(seconds:0));

Answer (score 0):

If the app fetches so many times in a short period of time it the fetch calls are [throttled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios#throttling_3). Because of the throttling limits, it is not possible for your app to immediately see changes in Remote Config values. Cached values will be used until the next fetch is allowed. The default cache expiration is 12 hours. This is done to optimize the network usage by Remote Config feature.

> Keep in mind that this setting should be used for development only,
> not for an app running in production. If you're just testing your app
> with a small 10-person development team, you are unlikely to hit the
> hourly service-side quota limits. But if you pushed your app out to
> thousands of test users with a very low minimum fetch interval, your
> app would probably hit this quota.